# storing previous states of a hook

Tags: react-hooks, react-state, react-state-management

I want to print the current and previous value of a state, I have a piece of code that does the job

```js
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] =  useState("");
  const prevValue = useRef('')
  useEffect(() => {
    prevValue.current = value;
  }, [value]);
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={value}
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div>
        Curr Value: {value}
      </div>
      <div>
        Prev Value: {prevValue.current}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But the problem with it is if I have some other state that is being set through, say, a button, it will cause the prev value to be same as current value. I'm looking for a way to prevent this, can someone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the `ref` with `useEffect` works for a single render, because the `ref` is updated after the content has been rendered.

As you can see in here, the `useEffect` is triggered when value changes. This means that at the end of each render cycle, `prevValue.current` equals `value`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    prevValue.current = value;
  }, [value]);
```

If another render is triggered by an unrelated update, the `ref` is already equal to the current `value`, and both are re-rendered.

To always maintain the `ref` one step behind the `value`, use an [updater function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) when setting the state. The updater function is called with the previous state, that you can store in the `ref`. Return the new state from the function to update the state.

The the example, you can see that the the ref always equals to the previous value, even if another update (clicking the button) causes a re-render:

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React;

function App() {
  const [anotherValue, setAnotherValue] = useState(0);
  const [value, setValue] =  useState('');
  const prevValue = useRef('');
  
  const onChange = e => {
    const newVal = e.target.value;
    
    // use an updater function
    setValue(prev => {
      prevValue.current = value; // set the previous value the the ref
      return newVal; // return the updated value to the state
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <div>
        Curr Value: {value}
      </div>
      <div>
        Prev Value: {prevValue.current}
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => setAnotherValue(v => v +1)}>
        Another value: {anotherValue}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I'm little confused, can you please explain a bit more about why does this work? Isn't button's click causing render and because of it prevValue render it current value opposed to earlier case when the there is no re-render and old value is rendered?

Comment: See updated answer, and read a bit on how `useEffect` works.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const { useState, useReducer, useEffect } = React;

function usePreviousReducer(state, action) {
  return { current: action.payload, previous: state.current };
}

function usePrevious(value) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(usePreviousReducer, {
    current: value,
    previous: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ payload: value });
  }, [value]);

  return state.previous;
}

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [valuer, setValuer] = useState(1);
  const prevValue = usePrevious(value);

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setValuer((prevValuer) => prevValuer + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Change Other State</button>
      <div>Curr Value: {value}</div>
      <div>Prev Value: {prevValue}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The usePrevious custom hook is used to keep track of the previous value of the value state. The hook only updates when value changes, and it won't be affected by changes in other states.

Comment: But it doesn't solve my use case, I want to use the prev value maybe pass it to a component etc, the code that I mentioned was just a basic one that does the bare minimum job but have potential flaws

Comment: i have updated the answer hope thats works

Comment: this will still not serve the issue, try having a button in the app and create a state for it, click on button to se what is happening

Comment: added the button looks okay

Comment: I meant try setting some state on click of button

Comment: updated the code with usePreviousReducer function is used with useReducer to manage the previous state.